# Very confused about the seatpost clamp

Tags: saddle, seatpost, clamp

I can't figure the seatpost clamp on my bicycle (maybe it's stuck?). I've had it for a few months, it's quite old. I hit a bump in the street and the force lowered the seat but now I can't figure out how to open/loosen the lever. I thought it was a standard quick release but it does not seem so.

[image: seat clamp]

Comment: Looks like it' just threaded, and the pin is so you don't need tools? Can you loosen it by rotating CCW? On the other side (not shown in the picture) ther's probably just a bolt?

Comment: Very cool bike from what I see.

Comment: As stijn said,, probably a bolt. What does the other side look like?  When you turn the lever counter clockwise,  watch the bolt head on the other side. Does it spin? If so, you'll need to put a wrench on the bolt while turning the lever.

Answer (score 3):

Turning the lever will not tighten or loosen the clamp.

The lever is a handle to allow you to twist what would normally be a nut by hand - instead of using a wrench.

Using the lever as a handle twist push down on the lever and move the "nut" counter clockwise until it comes off.
[image]
Put just a tiny dab of grease on the threads of the bolt and re-assemble.
The grease will make it easier to get the clamp tight enough to hold the seat post - and protect against rust.

While you are there it would be good to remove the seat post completely and put a little grease on the seat post in a super thin coat and then re-assemble. This will protect the seat post from rusting to the inside of the frame.

If you have no grease a little oil is second best.

Comment: Thanks everyone! A little bit of grease and manpower did the trick ! This is an old bike given to me by my university where I teach and it's been repaired many times so I was wondering if this was something else to get checked.